# Как работает метод String.Compare?

Tags: c#

Уже всю информацию перерыл.
Не могу понять он сначала сравнивает символы каждой строки между собой, если они все равны то сравнивает уже длина?

```
string a = "AAA";
string b = "AAB";
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(a,b));//Выводит -1.
```

В одном источнике говорится что Левая строка меньше правой, в другом что первая строка стоит перед второй в алфавитном порядке. А алфавитный порядок устанавливается по самому первому символу?
Весь день уже убил чтобы понять, помогите пж

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Меньше" и есть "стоит перед". Так же, как и с числами: 5 меньше 8 и стоит перед 8, если числовой ряд отсортировать по возрастнию.

> А алфавитный порядок устанавливается по самому первому символу?

Сначала по первому. Если одинаковый, то по второму, и т.д.

Comment: Сначала по длине вроде, потом по содержимому, не?

Comment: @aepot хм, похоже на то. Получается, в c# "z" меньше, чем "aa".